# Cut a video using timecode inserted by an external device

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have 2 cameras and each of them is attached to their own external device which is inserting the timecode into the mp4 stream of the video. These devices are in sync when they insert the timecodes. These cameras are started at different times. Ex: Camera1 is started at 11:15 AM and camera2 is started at 11:20 am.

What I want to do is I want to synchronize the 2 videos. For that I need to extract timecode of the first frame of camera2 (which started at 11:20 am) and then cut the video from camera1 till that timecode. Basically I need to cut video clip from camera1 from 11:15 to 11:20.

How can this be done? Any idea?

Comment: The easy answer is "do it manually". The automated solution involves exporting the frames, running OCR on them and doing the cutting. This could all be programmed but your would have to write the program yourself. Give it a try and post on stack overflow if you need help with the code.

Comment: Why OCR? I believe OP is referring to the tmcd track, not a burn-in. OP, please clarify.